# Giving indentation or space error in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

[image: getting indentation or space error in python 3]

I am just trying to play a sound in the script

The error I am getting

> "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation".

Code snippet:

```
    if flag >= frame_check:
                    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
                    cv2.putText(frame, "****************DANGER!****************", (10, 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    cv2.putText(frame, "****************DANGER!****************", (10,325),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Comment: Specify what error or warning occurs and also, do not post the code as image.

Comment: Attach more details about what you struggle with and what is the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

Either other lines are indented using tabulations : `\t` and this line is indented using spaces, or vice-versa.

Indentation has to be consistent in a python script. Use either spaces or tabulations, but not both.

You can use tabnanny to get a more detailled message :

https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/tabnanny.html

**Edit along your edit on your post with the code.**

Clearly the winsound line is indented using spaces, and other lines are indented using tabulations. Chose one way to indent and stick to it.

Comment: I am tryig both with space and tab to enter the line.But giving me the same  error. :(

Comment: Maybe your editor converts tab to spaces...
Try to convert all tabs to space in your script, searching and replacing \t by four spaces